# How to get 'average session duration' and 'Average pages viewed per visit' using google analytics api

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Hi I am using google analytics api `gapi` to find 'average session duration' and 'Average pages viewed per visit' of site

I had created a dashboard for that and the values are `00:02:30` and `4.58` respectively ...

I use the following code to find it

```
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('browserVersion'),array('sessions','sessionDuration','avgSessionDuration'), $sort_metric=NULL, $filter=NULL, $fromDate, $toDate,1,50);
echo $ga->getSessionDuration(); echo '<pre>';
echo $ga->getAvgSessionDuration(); 
exit;
```

But the values returned is `104409` `154.45118343195` any idea how to get the correct value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ga:sessionDuration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_sessionduration) is type time.  The total duration of user sessions represented in total seconds.

[ga:avgSessionDuration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_avgsessionduration) is also type time. The average duration of user sessions represented in total seconds.

The API returns raw unformatted data.  You will need to format it yourself. To format this in your code you should divide by 60 to get the number of minutes.